# Unable to find image 'xxxx' locally

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

Basically I created an asp.net mvc project. I added a Dockerfile in the project folder.

```
FROM microsoft/aspnet:1.0.0-rc1-update1
ADD . /app
WORKDIR /app/approot
EXPOSE 5004
ENTRYPOINT ["./web"]
```

Now I open Docker Quickstart Terminal on my Windows desktop. Running the command

```
docker build -t hellodocker:0.1.0 .
```

See the result 
[image: docker]

However I can't find the image when I run it.
[image: find]

So what is wrong?

**EDIT**

Thanks for the comment, I correct the typo. But there is an another error.
[image: typo]

**EDIT-1**

If I change the ENTRYPOINT as `ENTRYPOINT ["dnx", "-p", "project.json", "web"]`

Then I get another error:
`Unable to reslolve project from /app/approot`

**EDIT-2**

The context in the directory is as:
[image: directory]

Comment: You have a typo in the image name when you ran it. `hellowdocker`, note the `w`

Comment: @warmoverflow, thanks. I tried it again but there is another error. See my edit.

Comment: For the second error, you need to post the contents of your current directory. It sounds like the `web` file doesn't exist or isn't being copied over. Where is `web` relative to your project root? Is it at `approot/web` like your image assumes?

Comment: @AndyShinn, see my updated. EDIT-2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your project is being added to the image as `/app`. So, in the container, the `project.json` lives at `/app/project.json`. But your `WORKDIR` is set to `/app/approot`.

This effectively makes your `ENTRYPOINT` looking for `project.json` at `/app/approot`, which it does not exist. You'll either need to change `WORKDIR` to `/app` or `COPY . /app/approot`.

Comment: Am my dock run command correct? Because I changed `WORKDIR` to `/app`, then run the command `docker run hellodocker:0.1.0`. I got another error: `Unable to load application or execute command 'Microsoft.Aspnet.Server.Kerstrel'. Available commands: web, ef. `

Comment: I need your project.json file.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? I don't have any `project.json` file. I'm just answering your question in the context of Docker. I can't help with the .NET part.